# Cannot declare array of size 400000 in C

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, stack-overflow

I am trying to do following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 400000

void main() {
    int a[N];
}
```

I get a stackoverflow exception. My computer has 6GB of main memory so I cant be using it all up. How do I solve this problem? I using VS 2008 on Windows 7 and coding in C.

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but you shouldn't be declaring `void main`. [The correct return type for `main` is `int`.](http://c-faq.com/ansi/maindecl.html)

Answer (score 9):

The amount of stack size you're allowed to use is never going to be the full amount of main memory.

[You can use this flag to set the stack size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdkhxaks(v=VS.90).aspx)--which defaults to 1MB.  To store 400,000 ints you'll need at least 1.526 MB.

Why not allocate this on the heap instead of the stack?

Comment: Good advice in the other answers as well.  Keep in mind that the stack is used for many other things like local function variables and parameters, so it's important to know how to increase it when your program grows, but storing a big data structure like that in the stack segment would not be a typical practice.

Comment: @Bishop: I tried setting the /F option to /F 16000000 using the the Visual Studio development environment. However, it still does not work

Comment: 1600000 won't be sufficient.  That's *precisely* how much space is needed to store *just* that huge array of ints.  But there's other stuff that needs to go on your stack--all the frames for all the function calls leading up to this one, space for all the other function parameters and local variables, etc.  It should work if you give it more than that, like say 2MB.  (However, I agree with those below that you should probably use ``malloc`` for this.)

Answer (score 4):

When you define a variable like that, you're requesting space on the *stack*. This is the managed section of memory that's used for variables in function calls, but isn't meant to store large amounts of data.

Instead, you'd need to allocate the memory manually, on the heap.

```
int *a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

This defines `a` as a pointer to the memory on the heap. This will behave the same as the array, except you will need to manually

```
free(a);
```

when you finish using it or you'll create a memory leak.

Comment: Better: `int *a = malloc(N * sizeof *a);`

Comment: Better: `int *a = calloc(N, sizeof(int));`

Comment: Better: int *a = calloc(N, sizeof*a);

Answer (score 3):

Automatic variables are allocated on the stack, which is usually 1MB. To solve this, allocate the memory on the heap:

```
int *a = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * N);
```

When you're done with that memory, you can deallocate it:

```
free(a);
```

That will return the memory to the system.

Answer (score 1):

You need Stack Size larger than 400000*4=1600000 Bytes ~ 1.6 MB but the default stack size in visual studio is 1MB. There is 2 solutions:

1- you can change the stack size of you program by:

- right click  project, and choose properties from the menu .
- go to Configuration properties->Linker->Commandline, add this parameter

  /STACK:2000000

[image]

2- dynamic array to allocate over the heap, instead of static array , as all have said.