# Reduction algorithm implementation on openCL

Tags: opencl

I have the following "addition of 2^20 floats" implemented on OpenCL using two different kernels: One is supposed to treat values on scalar basis and the other will use float4 vectors. While the code builds without any compilation error, the program doesn't run. I've tried the code on both NVIDIA and AMD platforms and in both cases it fails. When I debug the code it gives the error of stack overflow. This code is a sample code of OpenCL in Action book. Any ideas why the code doesn't run?
Here is the code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#define PROGRAM_FILE "reduction.cl"

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1048576
#define NUM_KERNELS 2

#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#ifdef MAC
#include <OpenCL/cl.h>
#else
#include <CL/cl.h>
#endif

/* Find a GPU or CPU associated with the first available platform */
cl_device_id create_device() {

    cl_platform_id platform;
    cl_device_id dev;
    int err;

    /* Identify a platform */
    err = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't identify a platform");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Access a device */
    err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
    if (err == CL_DEVICE_NOT_FOUND) {
        printf(" GPU is not first! Going on CPU :(");
        err = clGetDeviceIDs(platform, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU, 1, &dev, NULL);
    }
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't access any devices");
        exit(1);
    }

    return dev;
}

/* Create program from a file and compile it */
cl_program build_program(cl_context ctx, cl_device_id dev, const char* filename) {

    cl_program program;
    FILE *program_handle;
    char *program_buffer, *program_log;
    size_t program_size, log_size;
    int err;

    /* Read program file and place content into buffer */
    program_handle = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (program_handle == NULL) {
        perror("Couldn't find the program file");
        exit(1);
    }
    fseek(program_handle, 0, SEEK_END);
    program_size = ftell(program_handle);
    rewind(program_handle);
    program_buffer = (char*)malloc(program_size + 1);
    program_buffer[program_size] = '\0';
    fread(program_buffer, sizeof(char), program_size, program_handle);
    fclose(program_handle);

    /* Create program from file */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource(ctx, 1,
        (const char**)&program_buffer, &program_size, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create the program");
        exit(1);
    }
    free(program_buffer);

    /* Build program */
    err = clBuildProgram(program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {

        /* Find size of log and print to std output */
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            0, NULL, &log_size);
        program_log = (char*)malloc(log_size + 1);
        program_log[log_size] = '\0';
        clGetProgramBuildInfo(program, dev, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
            log_size + 1, program_log, NULL);
        printf("%s\n", program_log);
        free(program_log);
        exit(1);
    }

    return program;
}

int main() {

    /* OpenCL structures */
    cl_device_id device;
    cl_context context;
    cl_program program;
    cl_kernel kernel[NUM_KERNELS];
    cl_command_queue queue;
    cl_event prof_event;
    cl_int i, j, err;
    size_t local_size, global_size;
    char kernel_names[NUM_KERNELS][20] =
    { "reduction_scalar", "reduction_vector" };

    /* Data and buffers */
    float data[ARRAY_SIZE];
    float sum, actual_sum, *scalar_sum, *vector_sum;
    cl_mem data_buffer, scalar_sum_buffer, vector_sum_buffer;
    cl_int num_groups;
    cl_ulong time_start, time_end, total_time;

    /* Initialize data */
    for (i = 0; i<ARRAY_SIZE; i++) {
        data[i] = 1.0f*i;
    }

    /* Create device and determine local size */
    device = create_device();
    err = clGetDeviceInfo(device, CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,
        sizeof(local_size), &local_size, NULL);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't obtain device information");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Allocate and initialize output arrays */
    num_groups = ARRAY_SIZE / local_size;
    scalar_sum = (float*)malloc(num_groups * sizeof(float));
    vector_sum = (float*)malloc(num_groups / 4 * sizeof(float));
    for (i = 0; i<num_groups; i++) {
        scalar_sum[i] = 0.0f;
    }
    for (i = 0; i<num_groups / 4; i++) {
        vector_sum[i] = 0.0f;
    }

    /* Create a context */
    context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a context");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* Build program */
    program = build_program(context, device, PROGRAM_FILE);

    /* Create data buffer */
    data_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(float), data, &err);
    scalar_sum_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, num_groups * sizeof(float), scalar_sum, &err);
    vector_sum_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE |
        CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, num_groups * sizeof(float), vector_sum, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a buffer");
        exit(1);
    };

    /* Create a command queue */
    queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device,
        CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, &err);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("Couldn't create a command queue");
        exit(1);
    };

    for (i = 0; i<NUM_KERNELS; i++) {

        /* Create a kernel */
        kernel[i] = clCreateKernel(program, kernel_names[i], &err);
        if (err < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't create a kernel");
            exit(1);
        };

        /* Create kernel arguments */
        err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &data_buffer);
        if (i == 0) {
            global_size = ARRAY_SIZE;
            err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], 1, local_size * sizeof(float), NULL);
            err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &scalar_sum_buffer);
        }
        else {
            global_size = ARRAY_SIZE / 4;
            err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], 1, local_size * 4 * sizeof(float), NULL);
            err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel[i], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &vector_sum_buffer);
        }
        if (err < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't create a kernel argument");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Enqueue kernel */
        err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel[i], 1, NULL, &global_size,
            &local_size, 0, NULL, &prof_event);
        if (err < 0) {
            perror("Couldn't enqueue the kernel");
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Finish processing the queue and get profiling information */
        clFinish(queue);
        clGetEventProfilingInfo(prof_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START,
            sizeof(time_start), &time_start, NULL);
        clGetEventProfilingInfo(prof_event, CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END,
            sizeof(time_end), &time_end, NULL);
        total_time = time_end - time_start;

        /* Read the result */
        if (i == 0) {
            err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, scalar_sum_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0,
                num_groups * sizeof(float), scalar_sum, 0, NULL, NULL);
            if (err < 0) {
                perror("Couldn't read the buffer");
                exit(1);
            }
            sum = 0.0f;
            for (j = 0; j<num_groups; j++) {
                sum += scalar_sum[j];
            }
        }
        else {
            err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue, vector_sum_buffer, CL_TRUE, 0,
                num_groups / 4 * sizeof(float), vector_sum, 0, NULL, NULL);
            if (err < 0) {
                perror("Couldn't read the buffer");
                exit(1);
            }
            sum = 0.0f;
            for (j = 0; j<num_groups / 4; j++) {
                sum += vector_sum[j];
            }
        }

        /* Check result */
        printf("%s: ", kernel_names[i]);
        actual_sum = 1.0f * ARRAY_SIZE / 2 * (ARRAY_SIZE - 1);
        if (fabs(sum - actual_sum) > 0.01*fabs(sum))
            printf("Check failed.\n");
        else
            printf("Check passed.\n");
        printf("Total time = %lu\n\n", total_time);

        /* Deallocate event */
        clReleaseEvent(prof_event);
    }

    /* Deallocate resources */
    free(scalar_sum);
    free(vector_sum);
    for (i = 0; i<NUM_KERNELS; i++) {
        clReleaseKernel(kernel[i]);
    }
    clReleaseMemObject(scalar_sum_buffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(vector_sum_buffer);
    clReleaseMemObject(data_buffer);
    clReleaseCommandQueue(queue);
    clReleaseProgram(program);
    clReleaseContext(context);
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the kernels which are stored in "reduction.cl" file:

```
__kernel void reduction_scalar(__global float* data, 
      __local float* partial_sums, __global float* output) {

   int lid = get_local_id(0);
   int group_size = get_local_size(0);

   partial_sums[lid] = data[get_global_id(0)];
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

   for(int i = group_size/2; i>0; i >>= 1) {
      if(lid < i) {
         partial_sums[lid] += partial_sums[lid + i];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
   }

   if(lid == 0) {
      output[get_group_id(0)] = partial_sums[0];
   }
}

__kernel void reduction_vector(__global float4* data, 
      __local float4* partial_sums, __global float* output) {

   int lid = get_local_id(0);
   int group_size = get_local_size(0);

   partial_sums[lid] = data[get_global_id(0)];
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

   for(int i = group_size/2; i>0; i >>= 1) {
      if(lid < i) {
         partial_sums[lid] += partial_sums[lid + i];
      }
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
   }

   if(lid == 0) {
      output[get_group_id(0)] = dot(partial_sums[0], (float4)(1.0f));
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe **how** it doesn't run (i. e. what error do you have)? I tried exactly your code and got in console:

*reduction_scalar: Check passed.
Total time = 253536

reduction_vector: Check passed.
Total time = 120288*

Comment: The window is pop-up and then it is not responding giving error suggesting to close or debug the program.

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Code is OK, as I see.

Comment: When I debug the program in VS2013, this is what I'm getting: "Unhandled exception at 0x00FE2A97 in contextCount.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000000, 0x00FF2000)." Any clue what should I look? I looked at every part of the code, couldn't see anything wrong.

Comment: In VS2013 you should see line with this error and stack trace. Possibly it's even better to run it step-by-step and figure out exact place where program causes exception

Comment: The problem fixed. Apparently, the array size was too big, I used malloc to create the same array and it worked now. Is this because of lack of memory in my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of `data` is too big. You need to dynamically allocate it by using `malloc`. Change of

```
float data[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

to

```
float *data = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)* ARRAY_SIZE);
```

has solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, your array was too large - it is default **stack** size issue in VS 2008. Now you create array in **heap**. Please refer to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212645/cannot-declare-array-of-size-400000-in-c) for details.

Comment: Oh, there are good descriptions on the link. I can increase the stack size and avoid overflow without using dynamic allocation. Thank you!